# how to add to sqlite in background

Tags: android

I have a Handler in my fragment that every 5 second add my location in SQLite.
What I need is to maintain this action in background when I open another fragment. How can I do this ?

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        Point p = ls.getPoint();
        String X = Double.toString(p.getX());
        String Y = Double.toString(p.getY());

        db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
        db.addLocation(new LocationXY(1,X,Y,"111"));

        clearmap();
        createPolyline();

        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: For background operations you can use `AsyncTask` or `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do both your fragments have in common? Their `Activity`! So run your handler in it.

As @Piyush pointed out, you should use an `AsyncTask` or a `Service` for background processes.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as @Piyush and @Ricardo suggest - use a service with a `Timer` and a `LocationListener`.

Then invoke `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourSqliteUpdateMethod, 0, 5000);` to update the database. See my service class below, which contains a lot of extra stuff, but you should be able to get what you want out of it...

```
public class TrackService extends Service {

/**
 * Edit these values to adjust the LOCATION UPDATE polling interval
 */
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 5;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE_METERS = 10f;

// Static timer variables
private static final long ONE_SECOND_IN_MILLIESECONDS = 1000;

// Create timer and set time as zero
private static Timer timer;
private long timeAsLong = 0;

/**
 * Track and submission specific variables
 */
private List<LocationTrack> trackArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private SubmissionSession submissionSession;
private long submissionID;
private boolean originAdded;

/**
 * LocationManager and listener variables
 */
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
};
/*private LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
};*/

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //Log.d("onCreate");

    timer = new Timer();
    initializeLocationManager();

    try {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (LOCATION_INTERVAL_SECONDS * 1000), LOCATION_DISTANCE_METERS,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);

        }
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e("fail to request gps location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.e("gps provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    /*try {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, (LOCATION_INTERVAL_SECONDS * 1000), LOCATION_DISTANCE_METERS,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        }
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e("fail to request passive location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.e("passive provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }*/
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent == null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        submissionID = prefs.getLong("SUBMISSION_ID", 0);
        submissionSession = new SubmissionSession(submissionID);
        trackArrayList = new Select().from(LocationTrack.class).where(Condition.column(LocationTrack$Table.SUBMISSIONID).eq(submissionID)).queryList();
        originAdded = false;
        timeAsLong = prefs.getLong("ELAPSED_TIME_AS_LONG", 0);
    } else {
        submissionID = intent.getLongExtra("SUB_ID", 0);
        submissionSession = new SubmissionSession(submissionID);
        // Stick in a reasonably sensible location to indicate to rest of app that a track's
        // being captured - this is deleted on 1st real data point from GPS captured
        trackArrayList.add(setLocationToLocationTrack(submissionSession.getLocation().getLocation()));
        originAdded = true;
        timeAsLong = intent.getLongExtra("START_TIME", 0);

    }
    // Start schedule at one second intervals, calling MainTask
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TrackService.updateTimerAndBroadcastTask(), 0, ONE_SECOND_IN_MILLIESECONDS);
    showNotification();

    //super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

/**
 * This method is necessary to increase the priority of the background services. It appeared that
 * some devices, when running eBird Tracks and then used camera, the Tracks service was killed
 * by Android due to limited resources. Upping the priority should reduce this.
 */
private void showNotification() {

    final int NOTIFICATION_FLAG = 101;
    final int ICON_SCALE_DIMENSION = 128;

    Intent mainIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName())
            .setPackage(null)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.lab_logo_square);

    PendingIntent pendingMainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            mainIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_kiwi_bird1600)
            .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, ICON_SCALE_DIMENSION, ICON_SCALE_DIMENSION, false))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.location_and_timer_services_running))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentIntent(pendingMainIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_FLAG, notification);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Need to call cancel AND purge when the user stops the list
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();

    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("fail to remove location listeners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    submissionSession.setTracks(trackArrayList);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation.set(location);

        // Code to add existing location object of site to tracks database on initiation
        // to at least give one sensible point. Necessary for assigning the submission as
        // an active recording - if no GPS picked up it was being overlooked in the methods
        // used to display Checklist in progress throughout app. On first real capture of
        // track data, it's deleted
        if (originAdded) {
            LocationTrack t = trackArrayList.get(0);
            t.delete();
            trackArrayList.remove(0);
            originAdded = false;
        }

        trackArrayList.add(setLocationToLocationTrack(location));
        sendDistanceToSubmissionActivity(Utils.routeDistance((ArrayList) trackArrayList));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //Log.d("onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //Log.d("onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        //Log.d("onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

// Send an Intent with an action named "tracks_update".
protected void sendDistanceToSubmissionActivity(double distance) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("tracks_update");
    intent.putExtra("distance", distance);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

/**
 * Method to create Locationtrack object and save it to SQLite
 *
 * @param loc
 * @return
 */
protected LocationTrack setLocationToLocationTrack(Location loc) {
    LocationTrack l = new LocationTrack();
    l.setSubmissionID(submissionID);
    l.setLat(loc.getLatitude());
    l.setLon(loc.getLongitude());
    l.setAccuracy(loc.getAccuracy());
    l.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    l.setValid(-1); // -1 signifies that the track is active (0 = invalid after editing, 1 = valid)
    //Log.d(l.getLat() + " " + l.getLon() + " saved()");
    l.save();
    return l;
}

/**
 * Inner main task, adds a second onto timeAsLong, then sends to SubmissionActivity
 */
private class updateTimerAndBroadcastTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        timeAsLong += ONE_SECOND_IN_MILLIESECONDS;
        sendDistanceToSubmissionActivity(timeAsLong);
    }

    // Send an Intent with an action named "timer_update".
    protected void sendDistanceToSubmissionActivity(long time) {
        //Log.d();
        Intent intent = new Intent("timer_update");
        intent.putExtra("long_time", time);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(TrackService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
}
```